# PHP upload to AWS S3 produces wrong destination path

Tags: php, codeigniter, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to upload an image file to my S3 storage using PHP. I use this helper library: https://github.com/psugand/CodeIgniter-S3

This is my PHP code:

```
$this->s3->putObject($this->s3->inputFile($tmp), 'dreamboks-assets-2017', '/test_example/' . basename($_FILES["userfile"]['tmp_name']), S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ);
```

The problem is S3 always creating an empty directory first before my desire directory (**test_example/**).

Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot S3]

How to avoid the unwanted empty directory? Is there any problem with my destination path parameter?

Comment: Try it with a relative path `$this->s3->putObject($this->s3->inputFile($tmp), 'dreamboks-assets-2017', 'test_example/' . basename($_FILES["userfile"]['tmp_name']), S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ);`

Comment: @ishegg Oh my bad, it works evidently. The folder is created on the next page, I didn't see it. Thank you.

Comment: added an answer so the question can be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a relative path. The API wrapper you're using is probably being thrown off by the leading `/`. So use it like this:

```
$this->s3->putObject(
    $this->s3->inputFile($tmp), 
    'dreamboks-assets-2017', 
    'test_example/' . basename($_FILES["userfile"]['tmp_name']), // relative path
    S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ
);
```

*Changed the formatting a bit to emphasize the change*